# Get value read from file by a function back in caller : Windows Store JavaScript App

Tags: javascript, windows-store-apps, winjs

I have written the following code [`Windows Store JavaScript App`] :

```
function get_ver(){
     get_text("verfile");
     // how to get value read by get_text [i.e. variable filedata] in this function??? 
}


function get_text(filepath) {
var p = "ms-appx:///" + filepath;
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(p);
Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri)
   .then(function (sampleFile) {
       return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(sampleFile);
   }).done(function (filedata) {

         document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = filedata;
        // want to return filedata to get_ver()
   }
   );
 }
```

I want to access the data read from 'verfile' [i.e. value of variable filedata] inside get_ver() may be as a return value. How to do so?

Instead of setting the value to innerHTML of an element I want that it should be returned to caller so that it can be processed further.

Comment: which value do you want?

Comment: Value of 'filedata' i.e. read from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your get_text method is calling an async API to do its work, it too becomes an async API. To return a value from it, then, you need to return a promise for that value. The easiest way to do this is to return the promise from the last *then* in the chain, and in that to return your final value from the innermost completed handler.

That is, write your method like this:

```
function get_text(filepath) {
    var p = "ms-appx:///" + filepath;
    var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri(p);
    return Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri)
        .then(function (sampleFile) {
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(sampleFile);
        }).then(function (filedata) {
            document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = filedata;
            return filedata;
        });
 }
```

Notice that I changed the "done" to "then" so it we get another promise back from the chain. I inserted a return filedata in that innermost completed handler, and a return statement before the first async call. What this does is return a promise from the whole chain, and the fulfillment value of that promise (according to the definition of then) is the return value of the last completed handler. (If you want more explanation about this, the second edition preview of my book, http://aka.ms/brockschmidtbook2) has a whole appendix called "Demystifying Promises."

Because get_ver now receives a promise back, you just add a completed handler to that promise (using done now because you're at the end of the chain):

```
function get_ver(){
     get_text("verfile").done(function (filedata) {
         // Use filedata
     });
}
```

Does that make sense? This is the general pattern for returning values from functions that themselves use async APIs, which makes those functions also async.

.Kraig

Comment: Thanks a lot! That works for me and yes I have to say good explanation. I am complete newbie to async stuff, your explanation made me really understood it.

Comment: Yep, it's been new for many of us. I finally sat down and picked through the details of promises (see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsappdev/archive/2013/06/11/all-about-promises-for-windows-store-apps-written-in-javascript.aspx), then things weren't quite so mysterious!